# How do I remove the water/temperature control faucet if there are no visible screws?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

My Delta branded shower faucet doesn't have any screws besides for two that hold the panel independently to the wall.

The handles have no apparent way to be removed.

Can anyone suggest a method that may be used to remove the handle?

I repeat, there is definitely no hole, screw or anything of that sort anywhere on the controls.

[image: Faucet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pull the outer temp control knob off](https://youtu.be/xxpY7O17jVY?t=2m22s), or pry it gently with a pair of non-marring tools from each side.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I received from Delta;

Thank you for contacting the Delta Faucet company. I will be happy to help you with your inquiry.

The front temperature dial of the Delta Cassidy Valve Trim T17497 model can be removed by grasping the piece on either side of the part and squeezing together gently. Then grasp the small handle and pull the cover off. You can also use a flathead screwdriver to pry it off.

If you have additional questions or concerns, please don't hesitate to reach out to us for answers. We appreciate your business and look forward to hearing from you!

Sincerely,

Candice
Delta Faucet
(800) 345-3358
Monday - Friday 8:00 AM - 7:00 PM ET
Saturday 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM ET

Comment: That's excellent info, straight from the horse's mouth. Can you confirm that your faucet looks like the one in the OP's post? If not, it's not of much actual use.

Answer (score 1):

Just did one similar, here's exactly what you do. Squeeze the cover on the sides (not the handle side), then gently pry it off from the side opposite the handle. The snaps that hold it in place under the handle and the side opposite the handle. To put it back on, slip the side opposite the handle first, and then gently push in on the handle.

[image]